How do i use AF_XDP, XDP and eBPF to send DNSpackets to resolver_addr
I am a XDP newbie and not much of a C guy, this program will be called from Golang using https://github.com/cilium/ebpf.
What i want is to use XDP to send DNS resolution packets to a specified resolver_addr and receive a response. This wil be a high thoroughput program.
Reading and reviewing docs shows it's not going to be easy to send using XDP, so alternatively i was thinking of trying out io_uring to send and receive with AF_XDP.
Couldn't get this to work as sendto() isn't allow at that kernel level.
#include <linux/bpf.h>         // BPF helper functions and macros
#include <bpf/bpf_helpers.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>    // Ethernet header struct
#include <linux/ip.h>          // IP header struct
#include <linux/udp.h>         // UDP header struct
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ETH_HLEN 14            // Ethernet header length

// DNS header struct
struct dns_hdr {
    __u16 id;
    __u16 flags;
    __u16 qdcount;
    __u16 ancount;
    __u16 nscount;
    __u16 arcount;
};

// DNS query struct
struct query {
    __u16 qtype;
    __u16 qclass;
};

// Key struct for perf event map
struct dns_key {
    __u32 saddr;
    __u32 daddr;
    __u16 sport;
    __u16 dport;
};

// Define perf event map
struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
    __uint(max_entries, 10240);
} dns_results SEC(".maps");

// Function to perform DNS resolution
__u32 resolve_dns(char *domain, char *resolver_addr) {
    // Open a raw socket for sending DNS queries
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("socket");
        return 0;
    }

    // Set up the destination address for the resolver server
    struct sockaddr_in dest_addr;
    dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest_addr.sin_port = htons(53); // DNS port
    inet_pton(AF_INET, resolver_addr, &dest_addr.sin_addr);

    // Create DNS query packet
    size_t query_len = strlen(domain) + 2; // domain length + NULL byte + 1 byte for query type
    __u8 *dns_query = (__u8 *)malloc(sizeof(struct dns_hdr) + query_len + sizeof(struct query));
    if (!dns_query) {
        perror("malloc");
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }

    // Construct DNS query header
    struct dns_hdr *header = (struct dns_hdr *)dns_query;
    memset(header, 0, sizeof(struct dns_hdr));
    header->id = htons(1234); // Random query ID
    header->flags = htons(0x0100); // Standard query
    header->qdcount = htons(1); // One question
    __u8 *query = dns_query + sizeof(struct dns_hdr);

    // Copy domain name into query
    strcpy((char *)query, domain);

    // Add query type (A record)
    query += strlen(domain) + 1; // Move pointer past domain name
    *(__u16 *)query = htons(1); // A record type
    *(__u16 *)(query + 2) = htons(1); // IN class

    // Send DNS query packet
    if (sendto(sockfd, dns_query, sizeof(struct dns_hdr) + query_len + sizeof(struct query), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&dest_addr, sizeof(dest_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("sendto");
        free(dns_query);
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }

    // Receive DNS response
    __u8 dns_response[2048]; // Adjust the buffer size as needed
    ssize_t num_bytes = recv(sockfd, dns_response, sizeof(dns_response), 0);
    if (num_bytes < 0) {
        perror("recv");
        free(dns_query);
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }

    // Parse DNS response and extract IP address
    struct dns_hdr *resp_header = (struct dns_hdr *)dns_response;
    if (ntohs(resp_header->ancount) < 1) {
        free(dns_query);
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;
    }

    __u8 *answer_ptr = dns_response + sizeof(struct dns_hdr) + query_len + sizeof(struct query);
    answer_ptr += 10; // Skip the name and type/class fields

    __u32 ip_addr = 0;
    memcpy(&ip_addr, answer_ptr, sizeof(ip_addr));

    // Close socket and free memory
    free(dns_query);
    close(sockfd);

    return ip_addr;
}

// XDP program
SEC("xdp_dns")
int dns_resolver(struct xdp_md *ctx, char *resolver_addr) {
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;
    struct ethhdr *eth = data;                    // Ethernet header
    struct iphdr *ip = data + sizeof(struct ethhdr);  // IP header
    struct udphdr *udp = (void *)ip + sizeof(struct iphdr);  // UDP header
    struct dns_hdr *dns = (void *)udp + sizeof(struct udphdr);  // DNS header
    struct query *q = (void *)dns + sizeof(struct dns_hdr);  // DNS query

    // Check packet boundaries
    if ((void *)ip + sizeof(struct iphdr) > data_end || 
        (void *)udp + sizeof(struct udphdr) > data_end || 
        (void *)dns + sizeof(struct dns_hdr) > data_end) {
        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    // Check if UDP and DNS packet
    if (ip->protocol != IPPROTO_UDP || ntohs(udp->dest) != 53) {
        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    // Parse DNS query
    if (ntohs(dns->qdcount) != 1) {
        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    // Extract domain name from DNS query
    char domain[256];
    __u8 *ptr = (__u8 *)q;
    int len = 0;
    while (*ptr != 0 && (void *)ptr < data_end) {
        int label_len = *ptr;
        ptr++;
        for (int i = 0; i < label_len && (void *)ptr < data_end; i++) {
            domain[len++] = *ptr++;
        }
        domain[len++] = '.';
    }
    domain[len - 1] = '\0';

    // Perform DNS resolution (pseudo code)
    __u32 ip_addr = resolve_dns(domain, resolver_addr);

    // Send result back to user space
    struct dns_key key = {
        .saddr = ip->saddr,
        .daddr = ip->daddr,
        .sport = udp->source,
        .dport = udp->dest,
    };

    int ret = bpf_map_update_elem(&dns_results, &key, &ip_addr, BPF_ANY);
    if (ret) {
        // Error handling
        return XDP_ABORTED; // Or another appropriate action
    }

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &dns_results, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &ip_addr, sizeof(ip_addr));

    return XDP_PASS;
}

// License
char _license[] SEC("license") = "MIT";


Are you trying to generate DNS queries with XDP or is something else generating those DNS queries and the XDP should just redirect them?

Now that you mention it, i suppose it would be alot of overhead generating the DNS queries in XDP, as that's what i was trying to do. I could  generate then in the Userspace golang program and have XDP redirect them. But how??
